# In what context kthreads are executed?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

System calls are executed within the calling process, interrupts can be executed within any process(when an interrupt occurs interrupt handler executes within the process that is currently running) but where kthreads are executed ? Let's assume that some function that is currently executing in kernel mode calls`kthreads_create`. This should spawn new kernel thread, but what will be the context of its execution ? Sorry if you consider my question dummy, I'm absolute newbie in Linux kernel

Answer (score 1):

A kernel thread gets its own process context. Kernel threads are listed by `ps`:

```
$ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 May29 ?        00:00:44 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 May29 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 May29 ?        00:00:05 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 May29 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7     2  0 May29 ?        00:00:01 [migration/0]
root         8     2  0 May29 ?        00:02:57 [rcu_preempt]
root         9     2  0 May29 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10     2  0 May29 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root        11     2  0 May29 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root        12     2  0 May29 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/1]
...
```

All the process names in [square brackets] refer to kernel threads.

See also https://lwn.net/Articles/65178/. `kthread_create` just creates a data structure. This data structure is then passed to `wake_up_process`, which runs the process.

It would seem that [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/basics.html#c.kthread_create_on_node) uses the terms *process*, *thread* and *task* rather loosely and more or less interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel threads are like normal processes, with the following two differences: (1) kernel threads are run in kernel mode, and (2) they do not have an address space of their own. Like the name says, kernel threads do not transition to user space, but continue to run in kernel mode. Kernel threads each have their own stacks, but otherwise the address space is shared with the rest of the kernel. In this respect they are like user space threads, but of course with the difference that user space threads live in the address space of the user level process they are started in.